# Draw a spark line with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, graphics, data-visualization, swiftui

I am using a set of data points (currently randomly generated), and drawing a line graph inside a box:

```
struct DrawLine: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 1.0)
                .fill(Color.purple)
                .frame(width: InstrumentPrices.boxWidth, height: InstrumentPrices.boxHeight, alignment: .center)

            SparkLine()

        }
        .frame(width: 0, height: 0).border(Color.black)
    }
}

struct SparkLine: View {
    @State var myPoints = InstrumentPrices.points

    static let gradientStart = Color(red: 239.0 / 255, green: 120.0 / 255, blue: 221.0 / 255)
    static let gradientEnd = Color(red: 239.0 / 255, green: 172.0 / 255, blue: 20.0 / 255)

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.white)
                .onTapGesture {
                    // print ("Tap!")
                    InstrumentPrices.resetPoints()
                    self.myPoints = InstrumentPrices.points
                }

            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Path { path in
                    path.move(to: InstrumentPrices.points[0])

                    self.myPoints.forEach {
                        path.addLine(
                            to: CGPoint(x: $0.x, y: $0.y)
                        )
                    }
                }
                .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                .fill (LinearGradient (
                    gradient: .init(colors: .init([Self.gradientStart, Self.gradientEnd])),
                    startPoint: .init(x: 0, y: 0),
                    endPoint: .init(x: 1.0, y: 0)
                ))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SwiftUI is new enough to me. I'm always looking for better code conventions. Any comments are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The role of your ZStack and border rectangle could be replaced with a .background or .overlay modifier on the Sparkline itself - would allow more flexibility in presentation at the point-of-usage.